# Tense of "ne sera jamais résolue"

Tags: temps-grammatical

I have encountered the following phrase on [Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9tournement_d%27avion): "L'affaire ne sera jamais résolue par le FBI."

The sentence seems to be referring to the future, but this doesn't make sense since the author doesn't know what the future holds. I would expect instead something like "L'affaire n'a jamais été résolue."

Assuming this is not a mistake, what is the explanation for the grammar of this sentence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called the *futur historique*, *futur de narration*, or *futur de perspective*.

The sentence refers to the future with the time of the event described as reference.

It is indeed mostly equivalent to *L'affaire n'a jamais été résolue par le FBI.*

Comment: Sans contexte, on pourrait également penser que "L'affaire ne sera jamais résolue par le FBI" est un futur simple. Si cela fait partie d'une histoire passée, alors oui, c'est un futur historique.

Comment: @Frank Oui, c'est vrai. Le questionnement de l'OP rendait cependant implicite que le temps utilisé ne pouvait pas être un futur simple et donc qu'il ne traduisait pas *The case will never be solved by the FBI*.

Answer (score 0):

Here is more context (as Wikipedia can be modified):

> 24 novembre 1971 : D. B. Cooper détourne le vol 305, après avoir reçu une rançon de 200 000 dollars, il sauta en parachute depuis l'arrière du Boeing 727 volant au-dessus de la région du Nord-Ouest Pacifique des États-Unis. L'affaire ne sera jamais résolue par le FBI.

Here there is indeed a mistake, but not where you think. "Sauta" should be in the present tense: "saute":

> 24 novembre 1971 : D. B. Cooper détourne le vol 305, [...] il saute en parachute [...]. L'affaire ne sera jamais résolue par le FBI.

Here we have present of narration: the events talked about are obvious set in the past, but are narrated through present tense to make it flow more smoothly. Future in this context means future relative to those past events, and it implies a strong conviction that it will stay true in the future from now: the person who wrote that believes this mystery is unlikely to be ever solved.